# Apache won't start on Fedora 15

Tags: fedora, systemd, apache-httpd, selinux

I can't get Apache to start on Fedora 15.  I downloaded a project into `/var/www/html` and changed myself to the owner (recursively), though I don't think I changed any SELinux contexts or anything like that.  When I run `service httpd start` I get:

> Starting httpd (via systemctl):  Job failed. See system logs and 'systemctl status' for details.
>   [FAILED]

And when I run `httpd -k start` as root I get:

> (98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 127.0.0.1:80

I'm not sure why but I think it has something to do with SELinux. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

You should do what the error output says:

> See system logs and `systemctl status` for details.

The second error message is pretty clear to me though: something is already running and using port 80. Run `netstat` as root to find out which program is occupying port 80:

```
netstat -ntlp
```

Maybe that's the httpd process that was started in the previous command. If so, kill it before trying again, or use `restart` instead of `start`.

Comment: `service httpd restart` output:

    Restarting httpd (via systemctl):  Job failed. See system logs and 'systemctl status' for details.
                                                           [FAILED]

and `systemctl --failed` output: 

    httpd.service             loaded failed failed     LSB: start and stop Apache HTTP Server

Answer (score 1):

Run this command as root to find out open ports:

```
netstat -tpln
```

You'll be able to see open ports under "Local Address" column. You'll also see PID of the process using the port in the last column. Try killing the pid by:

```
kill -9 PID
```

where PID is the process ID you just found.

Apache should start now.

Comment: There are a couple of items (sendmail and rpc.statd) running on various ports on 127.0.0.1, but nothing on 127.0.0.1:80, should I kill those processes?

Comment: No, don't kill them. Not sure what's wrong. You should system logs for more details.

Comment: where?  there's nothing in /var/log/httpd and `systemctl --failed` says: `httpd.service             loaded failed failed     LSB: start and stop Apache HT`. Where should I be looking?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too, and I solved it by reinstalling Apache. Type in the terminal (after `su` to root, or alternatively put `sudo` before the commands):

```
# yum remove httpd
Removed HTTPD 100%
# yum install httpd
Installed HTTPD 100%
```

And then do your work on the `.conf` files

And then type in the terminal:

```
sudo service httpd start
```

That should work.

Answer (score 0):

It's solved.  Some cool people in freenode/#fedora helped me find out that the `system-config-httpd` tool made some files (/etc/httpd/conf.d/system-config-httpd.conf and /etc/httpd/conf.d/system-config-httpd.conf.bak), and by moving/removing them it worked;  I'm not sure why.. something to do with systemd

Answer (score 0):

Just for educational purposes I will explain: You probably used the Fedora-provided GUI-based httpd configuration utility.  It creates the system-config-http.conf file.  Apache loads the "normal" conf.d first (which has a listen-port specified) and starts listening on that port.  Apache then loads *other* .conf files and processes them.  The new configuration file created by the GUI utility contains (td-da!) another 'listen' directive for port 80!  So Apache "sees" something already has port 80 occupied, so that is when Apache calls a halt to the startup process and exits completely.

The insideous part of all this it that you will *never* see port 80 occupied by *anything*.  I've been bitten by this years ago, and just now when I installed Fedora 15.  I thought *surely* they would have fixed their configuration utility to prevent this behavior a long time ago. Wrong!